# Google Play Game Services REST api Snapshot load/commit

Tags: rest, google-play-games

Anyone know if it is possible to load/commit snapshot through the Google Play Game Services REST api?

Im using this documentation: https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/snapshots

But it only seems to allow fetching Snapshots metadata.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the fields of the metadata is driveId.  This is the id to pass to the Drive API to read the data.  See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get for the API information for get.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would vote this up but I have not enough reputation. But really, thanks.