# Cloud Saving from a web page in Google Play Services

Tags: javascript, rest, google-play-services, google-play-games

Is it possible to create and load cloud saves in google play services from a webpage (via REST I imagine)? I can only seem to find documentation for saved games for C++/Android code.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965969/google-play-game-services-rest-api-snapshot-load-commit

Answer (score 2):

You may check [Get Started with Play Games Services for Web](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/gettingstarted).

> The REST API for Google Play games services allows you to issue REST
>   calls to set and retrieve game services data from your web game. You
>   can also use the Management API to make REST calls to reset the game
>   services data and perform other administrative functions.

*Note:* *[Links](https://github.com/playgameservices/web-basic-samples) to sample code were provided in the page as well. For the games to work properly, you need to set up your own versions in the Google Play Developer Console.*

Comment: No part of that answers my question I'm afraid, I looked there first.

Answer (score 2):

All of these methods require [authentication and authorisation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

To get a [saved game from the REST API call](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/snapshots/get):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/snapshots/{ID of save}
```

To get a [list of saved games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/snapshots/list):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/{me | ID of player}/snapshots
```

Saving a game is messier, as you have to use the [drives API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) to create the file:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files
```

Comment: That's half of the answer.. do you know if there is any guide to using the drives API to create save files? Where I put them or anything? Have you done it, or have seen anyone else do it?

Comment: @ChrisJefferson There's a runnable [JS quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js) that works for drive files.